# My custom admin module not displaying?

Tags: magento-1.6, php-5.4

I have created the custom admin module working fine.

but when my layout file(mca.xml) put on adminhtml->default->default->layout->mca.xml

it's working fine.

[image]

but when I put file into my package adminhtml->default->Course->layout->mca.xml 
it's not working? showing empty page.

[image]

can anyone tell me where I went wrong?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you set `adminhtml/default/Course/layout` to be your default adminhtml theme?

To do so you can specify the theme in your module's config.xml.

```
<stores>
    <admin>
        <design>
            <package>
                <name>default</name>
            </package>
            <theme>
                <default>Course</default>
            </theme>
        </design>
    </admin>
</stores>
```

Comment: hi adam, where it is?

Comment: Actually, without some coding this is not possible, so if you didn't change the core templating code I'm pretty sure you can only put it in `adminhtml/default/default/layout`

Comment: I set the Configuration->Design->Package->Current Package Name=Course. is there another option for admin panel

Comment: That's just for frontend, mot adminhtml. There is no easy way of changing the template directory of the adminhtml

Comment: I've edited my reply.

Comment: @Sander Mangel,If I put my layout file into adminhtml/default/default/layout, after updating magento version then my file will be overwritten. So, for this situation what should we do?

Comment: @AdamPaterson nice one! And I guess it will fallback to default/default?

Comment: @Adam Paterson, see my layout file is same location! but it's not working. then it put into adminhtml/default/default/layout then working.

Comment: @AdamPaterson, I set the </stores> settings in my config.xml file, but it's not working?

Comment: @AdamPaterson,actually I put it in default under my package, now I remove default folder in my package now working fine. thank you :)

Comment: @SanderMangel, thank you for supporting :)

Comment: I was going to suggest you check the directory structure of your package.

Comment: @AdamPaterson, One more doubt? If I create multiple module than I need to write this </stores> Code?

Comment: Nope, it only needs to exist once.